# Shell command to find lines common in two files

Tags: shell, command-line

I'm sure I once found a shell command which could print the common lines from two or more files. What is its name?

It was much simpler than [`diff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff).

Comment: The answers to this question aren't necessarily what everyone will want, since `comm` requires sorted input files.  If you want just line-by-line common, it's great.  But if you want what I would call "anti-diff", `comm` doesn't do the job.

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman is there a way to get common between two files when file1 contains partial pattern like `pr-123-xy-45` and file2 contains `ec11_orop_pr-123-xy-45.gz` . I need file3 containing `ec11_orop_pr-123-xy-45.gz`

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244351) for sorting text-files line-by-line

Answer (score 290, accepted):

The command you are seeking is [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html). eg:-

```
comm -12 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt
```

Here:

**-1** : suppress column 1 (lines unique to 1.sorted.txt)

**-2** : suppress column 2 (lines unique to 2.sorted.txt)

Comment: Typical usage : comm -12 1.sorted.txt 2.sorted.txt

Comment: While comm needs sorted files, you may take grep -f file1 file2 to get the common lines of both files.

Comment: @ferdy (Repeating my comment from your answer, as yours is essentially a repeated answer posted as a comment) `grep` does some weird things you might not expect. Specifically, everything in `1.txt` will be interpreted as a regular expression and not a plain string. Also, any blank line in `1.txt` will match all lines in `2.txt`. So `grep` will only work in very specific situations. You'd at least want to use `fgrep` (or `grep -f`) but the blank-line thing is probably going to wreak havoc on this process.

Comment: See [ferdy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61903/ferdy)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28051421/15168) below, and [Christopher Schultz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/276232/christopher-schultz)'s and my comments on it.  TL;DR — use `grep -F -x -f file1 file2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How would one have the outputs in different files?

Comment: @bapors: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you want the lines only in File1 in one file, those only in File2 in another, and those in both in a third, then (provided that none of the lines in the files starts with a tab)you could use`sed` to split the output to three files.  But is that what you're asking?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it is exactly what I was asking. I am not very confident in `sed`, would you show an example if it is okay?

Comment: @bapors: I've provided a self-answered Q&A as [How to get the output from the `comm` command into 3 separate files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336404/how-to-get-the-output-from-the-comm-command-into-3-separate-files/46336405#46336405)  The answer was much too big to fit comfortably here.

Comment: Does it require the files have same number of lines?

Comment: @Hi-Angel — no, the files can be different sizes.

Answer (score 74):

To easily apply the **comm** command to **unsorted** files, use Bash's [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ cat > abc
123
567
132
$ cat > def
132
777
321
```

So the files abc and def have one line in common, the one with "132".
Using **comm** on unsorted files:

```
$ comm abc def
123
    132
567
132
    777
    321
$ comm -12 abc def # No output! The common line is not found
$
```

The last line produced no output, the common line was not discovered.

Now use **comm** on sorted files, sorting the files with process substitution:

```
$ comm <( sort abc ) <( sort def )
123
            132
    321
567
    777
$ comm -12 <( sort abc ) <( sort def )
132
```

Now we got the 132 line!

Comment: so... `sort abc > abc.sorted`, `sort dev > def.sorted` and then `comm -12 abc.sorted def.sorted` ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks And then remember to remove the temporary files afterwards, and cope with cleaning up in case of an error. In many scenarios, the process substitution will also be a lot quicker because you can avoid the disk I/O as long as the results fit into memory.

Answer (score 40):

To complement the Perl one-liner, here's its `awk` equivalent:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{arr[$0];next} $0 in arr' file1 file2
```

This will read all lines from `file1` into the array `arr[]`, and then check for each line in `file2` if it already exists within the array (i.e. `file1`). The lines that are found will be printed in the order in which they appear in `file2`.
Note that the comparison `in arr` uses the entire line from `file2` as index to the array, so it will only report exact matches on entire lines.

Comment: THIS(!) is the correct answer. None of the others can be made to work generally (I haven't tried the `perl` ones, because). Thanks a million, Ms.

Comment: Preserving the order when displaying the common lines can be really useful in some cases that would exclude comm because of that.

Comment: In case anybody wants to do the same thing based on a certain column but doesn't know awk, just replace both $0's with $5's for example for column 5 so you get lines shared in 2 files with same words in column 5

Answer (score 25):

Maybe you mean `comm` ?

> Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
> With  no  options,  produce three-column output.  Column one
>   contains lines unique to FILE1, column
>   two contains lines unique to
>   FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

The secret in finding these information are the info pages. For GNU programs, they are much more detailed than their man-pages. Try `info coreutils` and it will list you all the small useful utils.

Answer (score 22):

While

```
fgrep -v -f 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt
```

gives you the differences of two files (what is in 2.txt and not in 1.txt), you could easily do a

```
fgrep -f 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt
```

to collect all common lines, which should provide an easy solution to your problem. If you have sorted files, you should take `comm` nonetheless. Regards!

Note: You can use `grep -F` instead of `fgrep`.

Comment: `grep` does some weird things you might not expect. Specifically, everything in `1.txt` will be interpreted as a regular expression and not a plain string. Also, any blank line in `1.txt` will match all lines in `2.txt`. So this will only work in very specific situations.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: It's possible to upgrade this answer to work better using POSIX [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) notations, which are supported by the `grep` found on most modern Unix variants.  Add `-F` (or use `fgrep`) to suppress regular expressions.  Add `-x` (for exact) to match only whole lines.

Comment: Why should we take `comm` for sorted files ?

Comment: @UlysseBN `comm` can work with arbitrarily large files as long as they are sorted because it only ever needs to hold three lines in memory (I'm guessing GNU `comm` would even know to keep just a prefix if the lines are really long).  The `grep` solution needs to keep all the search expressions in memory.

Answer (score 14):

If the two files are not sorted yet, you can use:

```
comm -12 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

and it will work, avoiding the error message `comm: file 2 is not in sorted order`
 when doing `comm -12 a.txt b.txt`.

Comment: You're right, but this is essentially repeating another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24851202/), which really doesn't provide any benefit.  If you decide to answer an older question that has well established and correct answers, adding a new answer late in the day may not get you any credit. If you have some distinctive new information, or you're convinced the other answers are all wrong, by all means add a new answer, but 'yet another answer' giving the same basic information a long time after the question was asked usually won't earn you much credit.

Comment: I didn't even see this answer @JonathanLeffler because this part was at the very end of the answer, mixed with other elements of answer before. While the other answer is more precise, the benefit of mine I think is that for someone who wants for a quick solution will only have 2 lines to read. Sometimes we're looking for detailed answer and sometimes we are in a hurry and a quick-to-read ready-to-paste answer is fine.

Comment: Also I don't care about credit / rep, I didn't post for this purpose.

Comment: Notice also that the process substitution syntax `<(command)` is not portable to POSIX shell, though it works in Bash and some others.

Answer (score 10):

```
perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/'  file1 file2
```

Comment: this is working better than the `comm` command as it searches each line of `file1` in `file2` where `comm` will only compare if line `n` in `file1` is equal to line `n` in `file2`.

Comment: @teriiehina: No; `comm` does not simply compare line N in file1 with line N in file2.  It can perfectly well manage a series of lines inserted in either file (which is equivalent to deleting a series of lines from the other file, of course).  It merely requires the inputs to be in sorted order.

Comment: Better than `comm` answers if one wants to keep the order.
Better than `awk` answer if one don't want duplicates.

Comment: An explanation is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552789/explain-this-perl-code-which-displays-common-lines-in-2-files

Answer (score 6):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1] ' file1 file2
```

Comment: This command does not work.

Answer (score 3):

On limited version of Linux (like a [QNAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QNAP_Systems#Product_overview) ([NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)) I was working on):

- *comm* did not exist
- `grep -f file1 file2` can cause some problems as said by @ChristopherSchultz and using `grep -F -f file1 file2` was really slow (more than 5 minutes - not finished it - over 2-3 seconds with the method below on files over 20 MB)

So here is what I did:

```
sort file1 > file1.sorted
sort file2 > file2.sorted

diff file1.sorted file2.sorted | grep "<" | sed 's/^< *//' > files.diff
diff file1.sorted files.diff | grep "<" | sed 's/^< *//' > files.same.sorted
```

If `files.same.sorted` shall be in the same order as the original ones, then add this line for same order than file1:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next}; $0 in a {print a[$0]}' files.same.sorted file1 > files.same
```

Or, for the same order than file2:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]=$0; next}; $0 in a {print a[$0]}' files.same.sorted file2 > files.same
```

Answer (score 2):

For how to do this for multiple files, see the linked answer to *[Finding matching lines across many files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19861397/2585303)*.

---

Combining these two answers ([answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12247194/2585303) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746495/2585303)), I think you can get the result you are needing without sorting the files:

```
#!/bin/bash
ans="matching_lines"

for file1 in *
do 
    for file2 in *
        do 
            if  [ "$file1" != "$ans" ] && [ "$file2" != "$ans" ] && [ "$file1" != "$file2" ] ; then
                echo "Comparing: $file1 $file2 ..." >> $ans
                perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/' $file1 $file2 >> $ans
            fi
         done 
done
```

Simply save it, give it execution rights (`chmod +x compareFiles.sh`) and run it. It will take all the files present in the current working directory and will make an all-vs-all comparison leaving in the "matching_lines" file the result.

Things to be improved:

- Skip directories
- Avoid comparing all the files two times (file1 vs file2 and file2 vs file1).
- Maybe add the line number next to the matching string

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you were asking, but something I think still may be useful to cover a slightly different scenario

If you just want to quickly have certainty of whether there is any repeated line between a bunch of files, you can use this quick solution:

```
cat a_bunch_of_files* | sort | uniq | wc
```

If the number of lines you get is less than the one you get from

```
cat a_bunch_of_files* | wc
```

then there is some repeated line.

Answer (score -2):

```
rm file3.txt

cat file1.out | while read line1
do
        cat file2.out | while read line2
        do
                if [[ $line1 == $line2 ]]; then
                        echo $line1 >>file3.out
                fi
        done
done
```

This should do it.

Comment: You should probably use `rm -f file3.txt` if you're going to delete the file; that won't report any error if the file doesn't exist.  OTOH, it would not be necessary if your script simply echoed to standard output, letting the user of the script choose where the output should go.  Ultimately, you'd probably want to use `$1` and `$2` (command line arguments) instead of fixed file names (`file1.out` and `file2.out`).  That leaves the algorithm: it is going to be slow.  It is going to read `file2.out` once for each line in `file1.out`.  It'll be slow if the files are big (say multiple kilobytes).

Comment: While this can nominally work if you have inputs which doesn't contain any shell metacharacters (hint: see what warnings you get from http://shellcheck.net/), this naive approach is terribly inefficient. A tool like `grep -F` which reads one file into memory and then does a single pass over the other avoids looping repeatedly over both input files.