# How can I show lines in common (reverse diff)?

Tags: command-line, diff

I have a series of text files for which I'd like to know the lines in common rather than the lines which are different between them. Command line Unix or Windows is fine.

File *foo*:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffccffe000)
libvlc.so.2 => /usr/lib/libvlc.so.2 (0x00007f0dc4b0b000)
libvlccore.so.0 => /usr/lib/libvlccore.so.0 (0x00007f0dc483f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0dc44cd000)
```

File *bar*:

```
libkdeui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5 (0x00007f716ae22000)
libkio.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkio.so.5 (0x00007f716a96d000)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffccffe000)
```

So, given these two files above, the output of the desired utility would be akin to `file1:line_number, file2:line_number == matching text` (just a suggestion; I really don't care what the syntax is):

```
foo:1, bar:3 == linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffccffe000)
```

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz My mistake. 1st line in 1st example supposed match last line in 2nd example. Thanks for catching the mistake; changing.

Comment: Another similar question with good answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/output-the-common-lines-similarities-of-two-text-files-the-opposite-of-diff

Comment: More general solution: We should submit a patch to **GNU diffutils**, to add an option for this, as it is really just a trivial negation in the equality test.

Comment: In case anyone was interested in writing such a patch: I just took a lengthy look at `diff`’s source code, and it’s not trivial at all, because it’s surprisingly large and messy. There is also no bug tracker, but merely a mailing list. So the best I can recommend, is to request this via mail. (I’d advise a clean rewrite from scratch though. My eyes still hurt. ;)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

On *nix, you can use [comm](http://www.ss64.com/bash/comm.html).  The answer to the question is:

```bash
comm -1 -2 file1.sorted file2.sorted 
# where file1 and file2 are sorted and piped into *.sorted
```

Here's the full usage of `comm`:

```
comm [-1] [-2] [-3 ] file1 file2
-1 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file1.
-2 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file2.
-3 Suppress the output column of lines duplicated in file1 and file2.
```

Also note that it is important to sort the files before using comm, as mentioned in the man pages.

Comment: comm [-1] [-2] [-3 ] file1 file2

-1 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file1. 
-2 Suppress the output column of lines unique to file2. 
-3 Suppress the output column of lines duplicated in file1 and file2.

Comment: @ojblass: Added this to the answer.

Comment: I discovered it is important the files be sorted before using comm. Perhaps add that to the answer.

Comment: short answer to the question: comm -1 -2 file1 file2

Comment: You can use this if your files aren't sorted: comm -1 -2 <(sort filename1) <(sort filename2)

Comment: In the "there's more than one way to skin a cat" department, `diff --unchanged-line-format='%L' --old-line-format='' --new-line-format=''` should produce identical output if, for some reason, comm is not available.

Comment: For ppl who are wondering: You can create `file1.sorted` via executing `sort file1 > file1.sorted`

Comment: And `sort -u file1 > file1.sorted` (--unique) the output will not have any repeated lines.

Answer (score 86):

I found this answer on [a question listed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581090/how-to-do-the-opposite-of-diff). I find [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to be more administrator-friendly than *[comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff/comm)*, so if you just want the set of matching lines (useful for comparing CSV files, for instance) simply use

```
grep -F -x -f file1 file2
```

Or the simplified [fgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff/fgrep) version:

```
fgrep -xf file1 file2
```

Plus, you can use `file2*` to glob and look for lines in common with multiple files, rather than just two.

Some other handy variations include

- `-n` flag to show the line number of each matched line
- `-c` to only count the number of lines that match
- `-v` to display only the lines *in file2* that differ (or use `diff`).

Using `comm` is faster, but that speed comes at the expense of having to sort your files first. It isn't very useful as a 'reverse diff'.

Comment: thanks Ryder, this could more useful than comm to many. You should link to the source answer (there are over half a dozen linked in Q in right-hand nav; it's a bit of work to find). It would also be nice to know how well grep does with un- or differently sorted input, and can print respective line numbers of matches.

Comment: @mattwilkie I felt the need to come back and clarify the use of the `-v` flag after I slipped up with it myself. Say you have two csv files file1 and file2, and they have both overlapping and non-overlapping rows. If you want all and only the non-overlapping rows, using `fgrep -v file1 file2` will only return the non-overlapping rows in file2, *and none of the additional non-overlapping rows in file1*. This may be obvious to some, but better to state the obvious than risk misinterpretation. In this particular case, sorting the files and using `comm` is still the better choice.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and clarifying Ryder. The extra attention is noted and appreciated (all t0o easy to let old things slip away!). I've switched the accepted answer because comm is clearly the community's choice, even though personally I still use this when sorting is unwanted overhead.

Comment: Another complication when using `grep`: any blank line in the first file will match every line in the second file. Make sure `file1` has no blank lines, or it will look like the files are identical.

Comment: `grep -Fxf` it is for me.

Comment: I find this better than `comm` because it is able to catch more similar lines between two different source codes. The idea is that, I want to determine if two source files are related sometime in their past versions.

Comment: Can we apply this for more than 2 files?

Comment: @alper technically yes; but then the -xf flag will match with any line in all the files following file1, and print out all the lines that match in every file listed after file1. Unless you specify the `-h` flag, the name of the file will be prefixed to every printed line.

Answer (score 37):

It was asked here before: *[Unix command to find lines common in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files)*

You could also try with Perl (credit [goes here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/command-to-display-lines-common-in-files/)):

```bash
perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/' file1 file2
```

Comment: thanks. I would have like to accepted both answers, as the perl one liner is cross platform. Comm gets the nod because it is simpler.

Comment: Perfect. Using cygwin terminal on windows and `comm` wasn't readily available. This was the perfect alternative.

Comment: This does not care about how the lines are ordered. It's more accurate than comm.

Comment: An explanation is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552789/explain-this-perl-code-which-displays-common-lines-in-2-files

Answer (score 25):

I just learned the *[comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)* command from the answers, but I wanted to add something extra: if the files are not sorted, and you don't want to touch the original files, you can pipe the output of the *[sort](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)* command.  This leaves the original files intact. It works in Bash, but I can't say about other shells.

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This can be extended to compare command output, instead of files:

```
comm -1 -2 <(ls /dir1 | sort) <(ls /dir2 | sort)
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that you might not want the result to be sorted. Like a program code file. Really, `diff` should have an option for this, just like `patch` has the `-r` option to reverse things.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} a[$1] ' file1 file2
```

Files are not necessary to be sorted.

Comment: This is unlike most of the answers here in that it allows you to reconstruct source templates. I have two files built from the same wrapper, with different text inserted at a few points. This answer enabled me to recover the wrapper.

Comment: Explanation can be found in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877 or in Idiomatic AWK blog referenced from one of its comments.

Comment: I think this should be $0, not $1, in both places. The question was about printing the lines in common, but here the awk script just checks for a common first field.

Answer (score 9):

I think `diff` utility itself, using its unified (-U) option, can be used to achieve effect. Because the first column of output of diff marks whether the line is an addition, or deletion, we can look for lines that haven't changed.

```bash
diff -U1000 file_1 file_2 | grep '^ '
```

The number 1000 is chosen arbitrarily, big enough to be larger than any single hunk of `diff` output.

Here's the full, foolproof set of commands:

```bash
f1="file_1"
f2="file_2"

lc1=$(wc -l "$f1" | cut -f1 -d' ')
lc2=$(wc -l "$f2" | cut -f1 -d' ')
lcmax=$(( lc1 > lc2 ? lc1 : lc2 ))

diff -U$lcmax "$f1" "$f2" | grep '^ ' | less

# Alternatively, use this grep to ignore the lines starting
# with +, -, and @ signs.
#   grep -vE '^[+@-]'
```

If you want to include the lines that are just moved around, you can sort the input before diffing, like so:

```bash
f1="file_1"
f2="file_2"

lc1=$(wc -l "$f1" | cut -f1 -d' ')
lc2=$(wc -l "$f2" | cut -f1 -d' ')
lcmax=$(( lc1 > lc2 ? lc1 : lc2 ))

diff -U$lcmax <(sort "$f1") <(sort "$f2") | grep '^ ' | less
```

Comment: I like this answer. I have two suggestions, though. 1. I'd add the option `-a` to grep command to avoid the "Binary file (standard input) matches" comment grep might add to output for some input files. 2.  I'd pipe the resulting lines through `cut --byte=2-` to restore the original format.

Answer (score 1):

Just for information, I made a little tool for Windows doing the same thing as "grep -F -x -f file1 file2" (As I haven't found anything equivalent to this command on Windows)

Here it is:
http://www.nerdzcore.com/?page=commonlines

Usage is "CommonLines inputFile1 inputFile2 outputFile"

Source code is also available (GPL).

Answer (score 1):

In ***Windows***, you can use a [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script with ***CompareObject***:

```
compare-object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru (get-content A.txt) (get-content B.txt)> MATCHING.txt | Out-Null #Find Matching Lines
```

**CompareObject:**

- IncludeEqual without -ExcludeDifferent: Everything
- ExcludeDifferent without -IncludeEqual: Nothing

Comment: What is the purpose of *"Out-Null"*?