# How to do the opposite of diff?

Tags: linux, shell, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to show lines in common (reverse diff)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Is there a command to do the opposite of diff? I want to compare two files if the same thing exists in both create a list of them. i am trying to figure out what entry's exist in both files.

Comment: You might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff and then mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: This might not get closed if you can edit and add specifics, like you want to do this on Linux, etc.

Comment: I it figured out i was unaware of the comm command before but anyways two lists want to know only what is the same comm -1 -2 file1 file2 > outputfile.txt worked thank you for your help. Probably the easiest answer for what i wanted.

Answer (score 36):

Here is a solution that WILL NOT change the order of the lines:

```
fgrep -x -f file1 file2
```

Comment: This is not a reverse diff, but may be useful nonetheless. It prints the lines in `file2` that exactly match some line in `file1`. 
`fgrep` searches for fixed string matches
`-f` uses file1 as a list of grep search patterns
`-x` print only lines matched entirely

Answer (score 12):

Use the join command:

`join a.txt b.txt`

assuming the files are sorted; if not:

```
sort a.txt > sorted_a.txt; sort b.txt > sorted_b.txt; join sorted_a.txt sorted_b.txt
```