# Finding common value across multiple files containing single column values

Tags: awk, text-processing, comm

I have 100 text files containing single columns each. The files are like:

```
file1.txt
10032
19873
18326

file2.txt
10032
19873
11254

file3.txt
15478
10032
11254
```

and so on. 
The size of each file is different.
Kindly tell me how to find the numbers which are common in all these 100 files.

[*The same number appear only once in 1 file.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472246/finding-common-value-across-multiple-files-containing-single-column-values#comment74003047_43473385)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

to find the common element in all files (assuming uniqueness within the same file)

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{for(k in a) if(a[k]==ARGC-1) print k}' files
```

count all occurrences and print the values where count equals number of files.

Answer (score 5):

This will work whether or not the same number can appear multiple times in 1 file:

```
$ awk '{a[$0][ARGIND]} END{for (i in a) if (length(a[i])==ARGIND) print i}' file[123]
10032
```

The above uses GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and ARGIND. There's easy tweaks for other awks if necessary, e.g.:

```
$ awk '!seen[$0,FILENAME]++{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) if (a[i]==ARGC-1) print i}' file[123]
10032
```

If the numbers are unique in each file then all you need is:

```
$ awk '(++c[$0])==(ARGC-1)' file*
10032
```

Comment: The same number appear only once in 1 file

Comment: OK the solutions I provided would obviously work for that case too but I added he trivial solution for just that case.

Comment: Pretty neat the "trivial solution". I had to stop for a second to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Files with a single **column**?

You can sort and compare this files, using shell:

```
for f in file*.txt; do sort $f|uniq; done|sort|uniq -c -d
```

Last `-c` is not necessary, it's need only if you want to count number of occurences.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpful.

Comment: `sort * | uniq -c -d` would appear to work with this (amount of) data.

Comment: No. It will not work, If you have file with multiple occurences of string.

Comment: @A.N. You are right, I missed that the limitation wasn't removed in the OP, just in the comments to Ed's answer.

Answer (score 0):

One using Bash and `comm` because I needed to know if it would work. My test files were `1`, `2` and `3`, hence the `for f in ?`:

```
f=$(shuf -n1 -e ?)                     # pick one file randomly for initial comms file

sort "$f" > comms 

for f in ?                             # this time for all files
do 
  comm -1 -2 <(sort "$f") comms > tmp  # comms should be in sorted order always
  # grep -Fxf "$f" comms > tmp         # another solution, thanks @Sundeep
  mv tmp comms
done
```

Comment: instead of `comm+sort` I would suggest using `grep -Fxf file1 file2`

Comment: Any ideas on how to pick one of the files to be the initial `comms`? Better than my `for ... break` :D?

Comment: I did try similar solution but didn't post it... don't forget to quote `"$f"`... coming to picking, would help to know file names and use bash extglob... `grep -Fxf file1.txt file2.txt > f1` and then `for f in !(file[12]).txt <code>`