# Finding common elements from 100 files all containing 3 columns but different number of rows

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have 100 files containing 3 columns and different no. of rows. All three columns contain repeating elements. I want to find the common elements among all 100 files.
The files look like:

**1.txt**

```
5901 5902   8229
5901 5902  17481
5901 5902  27561
5929 5930  12875
```

**2.txt**

```
5901 5902  8229
5929 5930  12875
```

and so on. 
Code which I am trying to use is as
for ((i=0;i<=100;i++))
do
comm -12 file-"$i".txt file-"$((i+1))".txt > common-element-"$i".txt
done

I have used comm command but that was only for 2 files. I have 100 such files.

Comment: what are your *the common elements* ?

Comment: The files which I have shown above have common elements like 5901 5902 8229

Comment: do add the `comm` command you tried for 2 files... did it solve for two files? if so, you could very well use a loop, like it was shown in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472246/finding-common-value-across-multiple-files-containing-single-column-values

Comment: You want to output any number, regardless of row or column, that appears in all 100 files?

Comment: Yes regardless of rows as column numbers are same. I want output for those numbers which are present in all 100 files

Comment: Using the loop can I am using following loop: for ((i=0;i<=100;i++))
do
comm -12 -nocheck-order file-"$i".txt file-"$((i+1))".txt > common-element.txt
done
Will it work for comparing elements among all 100 files ?

Comment: please click https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43542609/edit to add the code you tried to question and use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help if you face formatting issues

Answer (score 0):

if the values are unique within the file, you can count the occurrences of each row and select the ones that are equal to the number of files, which can be done with `uniq -c` after sorting all the files, but sorting not required with the alternative below.

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{$1=$1} ++a[$0]==(ARGC-1)' file{1..100}.txt

5901 5902  8229
5929 5930  12875
```

`$1=$1` statement is to normalize white space since it's not consistent in your example.

Comment: How to use the above mentioned awk command for 100 files since the above was for two files only.

Comment: there is no limit, you can list all names or use bash expansion as I did or globbing or all directory contents etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful.