# Percentage of matching lines across multiple files

Tags: bash, grep, comm

I am in the need of finding common lines across multiple files; more than 100 files with millions of lines each. Similar to this: [Shell: Find Matching Lines Across Many Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246910/shell-find-matching-lines-across-many-files).

However, I would like to find not only shared lines across all files but also those lines that are found in all files except one, all files except two and so on. I am interested in using percentages to do so. For example, which entries show up in 90% of the files, 80%, 70% and so on. As an example:

File1

```
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

File2

```
lineB
lineC
lineD
```

File3

```
lineC
lineE
lineF
```

Hypothetical output for the sake of demonstration:

`<lineC> is found in 3 out of 3 files (100.00%)`

`<lineB> is found in 2 out of 3 files (66.67%)`

`<lineF> is found in 1 out of 3 files (33.33%)`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, show some example file contents of multiple files with expected output.

Comment: Please, read how to [ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edited my question.

Comment: what you are showing won't do what you ask. you mentioned 1 million lines of text. there i imagine you won't need to show the stats for all the lines. also, running that scale of input, a naive algorithm should be very slow. are you asking for practical algorithms as well?

Comment: Why show a series of lines as the desired output and then say "I would prefer a table" instead of simply showing a table as the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will try to be more clear in the future. The answer shown below is working. The speed of the algorithm seems quite reasonable according to my data.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for its multidimensional arrays:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {nfiles = ARGC-1}
    { lines[$0][FILENAME] = 1 }
    END {
        for (line in lines) {
            n = length(lines[line])
            printf "<%s> is found in %d of %d files (%.2f%%)\n", line, n, nfiles, 100*n/nfiles
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}
```

```
<lineA> is found in 1 of 3 files (33.33%)
<lineB> is found in 2 of 3 files (66.67%)
<lineC> is found in 3 of 3 files (100.00%)
<lineD> is found in 1 of 3 files (33.33%)
<lineE> is found in 1 of 3 files (33.33%)
<lineF> is found in 1 of 3 files (33.33%)
```

The order of output is indeterminate

Comment: Thanks, Glenn! This works fine and it's fast enough for my needs.