# How to find duplicate lines across 2 different files? Unix

Tags: file, unix, diff, similarity

From the unix terminal, we can use `diff file1 file2` to find the difference between two files. Is there a similar command to show the similarity across 2 files? (many pipes allowed if necessary.

Each file contains a line with a string sentence; they are sorted and duplicate lines removed with `sort file1 | uniq`.

`file1`: http://pastebin.com/taRcegVn

`file2`: http://pastebin.com/2fXeMrHQ

And the output should output the lines that appears in both files.

`output`: http://pastebin.com/FnjXFshs

I am able to use python to do it as such but i think it's a little too much to put into the terminal:

```
x = set([i.strip() for i in open('wn-rb.dic')])
y = set([i.strip() for i in open('wn-s.dic')])
z = x.intersection(y)
outfile = open('reverse-diff.out')
for i in z:
  print>>outfile, i
```

Comment: What do your files look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show lines in common (reverse diff)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Comment: Most times a string of human language sentences. Sometimes columnized with more information too.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of two simple files and the sort of output you'd like to get from that input? It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve. It would also be helpful to understand a bit more the motivation for doing this, as someone may have a different approach to solve your problem.

Comment: And you want the output to be a list of the lines that both files have in common?

Comment: @MartinAtkins, updated the question with the desired output.

Comment: Can the same line appear more than once in a given file?  Is the order of the lines in the files relevant?

Comment: The same line shouldn't have appeared more than once in the file. i think i did `sort file1 | uniq` before coming the files. The order of the lines shouldn't be a problem too since the sort would have sorted them alphabetically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @tjameson mentioned it may be solved in another thread.
Just would like to post another solution:
`sort file1 file2 | awk 'dup[$0]++ == 1'`

1. refer to [awk guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) to get some awk
   basics, when the pattern value of a line is true this line will be
   printed
2. dup[$0] is a hash table in which each key is each line of the input,
   the original value is 0 and increments once this line occurs, when
   it occurs again the value should be 1, so `dup[$0]++ == 1` is true.
   Then this line is printed.

Note that this only works when there are not duplicates in either file, as was specified in the question.

Comment: Can you explain how `awk 'dup[$0]++ == 1'` works? Your solution is much better than the confusing `comm`

Comment: `awk` uses `pattern { action }` notation.  Since this is not in braces, it is a pattern.  `$0` is the current line. `dup[$0]` is an associative array indexed by the lines; when first created, the value is 0; `dup[$0]++` post-increments the value, so it returns 0 the first time, and 1 on the second time, etc.  When its value is 1, the condition is true so the default action (print the line) is executed.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to get a list of repeated lines without resorting to AWK, you can use [`-d` flag to uniq](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq):

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -d
```

Comment: Also, dropping the -d gets you just all the distinct lines from both files which is what I was looking for.