# awk: How can I use awk to determine if lines in one file of my choosing (lines 8-12, for example) are also present anywhere in another file

Tags: awk

I have two files, `baseline.txt` and `result.txt`.  I need to be able to find if lines in `baseline.txt` are also in `results.txt`.  For example, if lines 8-12, is in `results.txt`. I need to use awk.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are sorted, it looks like [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) is more of what you're looking for if you want lines that are present in both files:

```
comm -12 baseline.txt results.txt
```

The `-12` argument suppresses lines that are unique to `baseline.txt` and `results.txt`, respectively, leaving you with only lines that are common to both files ("suppress lines unique to file 1, suppress lines unique to file 2").

If you are dead set on using `awk`, then perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470260/how-to-find-duplicate-lines-across-2-different-files-unix) can help you.

Comment: I have to use awk, and I am not trying to look for duplicate lines, I am searching if lines 8-12 of file1 is in file2.  I have gotten this much "lines=$(nawk '{ if (NR >= 8 && NR <= 12) print $0}' test/.baseline)", but that only prints out lines 8-12, how can I use awk to search if those lines are in the results.txt.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to be more clear, ie: "How can I use awk to determine if lines in one file of my choosing (lines 8-12, for example) are also present anywhere in another file?"