# Explain this perl code which displays common lines in 2 files

Tags: perl

How does this perl one-liner display lines that 2 files have in common?

```
perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/'  file1 file2
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `-n` command line option transforms the code to something equivalent to

```
while ($ARGV = shift @ARGV) {
  open ARGV, $ARGV;
  LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    $seen{$_} .= @ARGV;
    print $_ if $seen{$_} =~ /10$/;
  }
}
```

While the first file is being read, `scalar @ARGV` is `1`. For each line, `1` will be appended to the `%seen` entry.

While the second file is being read, `scalar @ARGV` is `0`. So if a line was in file 1 and in file2, the entry will look like `1110000` (it was 3× in file1, 4× in file2).

We only want to output common lines exactly one time. We do this when a common line was first seen in file2, so `$seen{$_}` is `1110`. This is expressed as the regex `/10$/`: The string `10` must appear at the end.

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer! I didn't realize that `@ARGV` changes as files are processed. So the `%seen` hash springs into existence when an entry is assigned in it. What's the default value for the hash entry, is it the empty string?

Comment: @Kelvin There is still a considerable amount of magic going on here. In a larger program, one would `use strict` and declare the `%hash` with `my %hash` outside the loops. If a hash entry doesn't exist, the value is `undef` (`null` or `nil` in other languages). But when an entry is treated as a string, it is the empty string. Thus it Does What I Mean.

Comment: When values of data structures (hashes, arrays) just spring into existence, this is called [*autovivification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification). This is especially useful for creating complex data structures, or such counting stuff. E.g. `my %hash; $hash{foo}{bar} = 42` autovivifies a hash in the `foo` entry.

Comment: @amon: "when an entry is treated as a string, it is the empty string" *by `.=`*, not all operations.

Comment: @ysth No, it's really *all* operators. However, some operators such as `.=`, `++`, and dereferencing are special-cased to not generate warnings when they encounter an `undef` lvalue.

Comment: @amon: it is treated as 0 by numeric operators; there's also autovivification which treats it as the appropriate reference type.

Comment: @KarelBílek I assume your comment was meant be on the code in the question and not amon's answer. And I agree with you.

Comment: Great explanation!  The same concept can be extended to 3 files:  `perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /2+1+0$/' file1 file2 file3`

Answer (score 3):

@ARGV is shifted when opening the first file. In scalar context, it now returns 1 (because it has one member, the second file). For each line, this 1 is appended to the hash %seen. When the second file is opened, @ARGV is shifted again and is now empty, so returns 0 in the scalar context. `/10$/` means "the line was seen in file1 and now it has been seen in file2 for the first time".