# Merge two files on Linux keeping only lines that appear in both files

Tags: linux, centos

In Linux, how can I merge two files and only keep lines that have a match in both files?

Each line is separated by a newline (`\n`).

So far, I found to `sort` it, then use `comm -12`. Is this the best approach (assuming it's correct)?

fileA contains

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

fileB contains

```
aaa
ddd
eee
```

and I'd like a new file to contain

```
aaa
ddd
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff

Comment: If sorting is an option (or the files are already sorted), then `sort` plus `comm` is the way to go.

Comment: See also [Unix command to find lines common in two files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files/373819#373819).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided both of your two input files are [*lexicographically sorted*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), you can indeed use [`comm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm_%28Unix%29):

```
$ comm -12 fileA fileB > fileC
```

If that's not the case, you should [`sort`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29) your input files first:

```
$ comm -12 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) > fileC
```