# Write shell script to find content of one file into another and display all ocurrence

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

i need to write a shell script to find the content of one file[all the content of this file] into another file along side it displays the line number and total number of occurrence of the content as an output .

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="/home/ashish/contents.txt"

while read -r line; 
do
    grep $line /home/ashish/first.csv
done < "$file"
```

for example :
first file contain this code 
"at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) - waiting on <0x272d5c18> (a weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl) at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.waitForData(ResponseImpl.java:76) - locked <0x272d5c18> (a weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl) " 
second file contain code in bulk amount so i need to count the number of occurrence of code in the first file inside second file 
Output=number of times code in first file occur in second file along with line numbers (if possible).

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: bluefoggy: It is perfectly clear what he needs. @Ashish: I would do this in two steps: the first script creates a longer script with grep's for every entry in contents.txt. You can automatically delete it afterwards.

Comment: let us suppose we have two files as first and second and the content of first and second are as follows
first :
hello hi

second :
hi hello my name is ashish
he said hi hello to her

desired output should be 
2// which is the occurance of content if first in second
line 1 line 2 which state the line number where it occur

Comment: Please edit your question and show the expected output there.

Comment: first file contain this code 
"at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x272d5c18> (a weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl)
  at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.waitForData(ResponseImpl.java:76)
  - locked <0x272d5c18> (a weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl) "

second file contain code in bulk amount so i need to count the number of occurrence of code in the first file inside second file
Output=number of times code in first file occur in second file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show lines in common (reverse diff)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply grep the contents and there could be repeated entries so at the end just pipe the output to `sort -u` or `sort | uniq`

like:

```
while read -r line;do  echo -n $(grep -c $line /home/ashish/first.csv); echo "  $line";done <"$file" | sort -u
```

`grep -c` will count the occurances
`sort -u` will sort the output uniquely

Comment: i need to search for multiple lines and this is searching for only single line. i mean if i have to search multiple strings into  the second file