# Linux command to find similarity in two text files.If both have matching tring, push it to a text file

Tags: linux

file1.txt

> Message Id:4401811003996404

file2.txt

> Message Id:4401811003996404 End Time
>
> Message Id:4401811007868646 End Time

I tried to use cut to trim the End Time from the `file2.txt` but it cut digits too.

Also tried comm -12 `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, output was blank.

I want output something like this

> Message Id:4401811003996404

Comment: What was your code to trim the end time? Maybe with a tweak it would work.

Comment: I used cut -d : -f5,6.It displayed till Message Id:4401811003996404 End Time.cut -d : -f5 displayed only Message Id

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show lines in common (reverse diff)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-to-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple:

two files, uno and due.

```
[root@srvrux33 ~]# cat uno
1 end
2 end
3 end
1 end
[root@srvrux33 ~]# cat due
1
3
[root@srvrux33 ~]#
```

You can achieve your result in the following way:

```
[root@srvrux33 ~]# for L in $(cat due); do grep $L uno| uniq | awk '{ print $1 }'; done
1
3
[root@srvrux33 ~]#
```

Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks Giova.It worked.Could you please explain me the logic.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for the above scenario.But to make sure it is not printing value from one of the file twice i added start and end to above file.This way below                                                                           file1.txt Start Message Id:4401811003996404                                           and file2.txt
    End Message Id:4401811003996404 End Time
   End Message Id:4401811007868646 End Time.It displayed content of file2.txt repeated.May be if i understand logic i would be able to find a way to make this work.Thanks for the help