# How to select all the matched files using vimdiff so that non matching files are deled

Tags: python, linux, awk, grep, vimdiff

I have a ligand folder `lig1` containing about 2000 files in `.pdbqt` format like:

```
compound_117_uff_e=945.53.pdbqt
compound_11800_uff_e=593.20.pdbqt
compound_11801_uff_e=543.18.pdbqt
compound_11802_uff_e=221.66.pdbqt
compound_11803_uff_e=689.82.pdbqt
compound_11804_uff_e=397.25.pdbqt
compound_11805_uff_e=482.14.pdbqt
compound_11806_uff_e=485.90.pdbqt
compound_11807_uff_e=437.60.pdbqt
```

I have used the `vimdiff` command:

```
$ vimdiff lig1 d1.csv
```

This shows some matching files between `lig1` and `d1.csv` like:

```
compound_11800_uff_e=593.20.pdbqt
compound_11801_uff_e=543.18.pdbqt
compound_11805_uff_e=482.14.pdbqt
```

We can use "delete" key of the computer to delete one by one files in `lig1` folder. How to delete all the non-matched files at once from command line so that `lig1` folder contains only matched ones.
The actual folder `lig1` and file `d1.csv` can be extracted from:
https://github.com/dharmapaudel/ligand-screening

I want to make `lig1` folder of the  matched file. That is i want to make the `lig1` folder that contains only  file for example:

```
compound_11800_uff_e=593.20.pdbqt
compound_11801_uff_e=543.18.pdbqt
compound_11805_uff_e=482.14.pdbqt
```

and delete all the non-matched file.

Comment: If it does not need to be with Vim, then some of these answers may be for you [How can I show lines in common (reverse diff)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746458/how-can-i-show-lines-in-common-reverse-diff)

Comment: The problem is that "lig1" be a folder while d1.csv be a file. Your suggestions work for both files.