# Find lines common to several files

Tags: linux, compare, comm

I'm trying to determine which header declares a specific function. I've used `grep` to find instances of the function's use; now, I want to find which header is included by all the files. I'm aware of the [`comm` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files); however, it can only compare two *sorted* files. Is there a Unix utility that can find the common lines between an arbitrary number of *unsorted* files, or must I write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cat *.c | sort | uniq -c | grep -e '^ *COUNT #include'
```

where `COUNT` is the number of files passed to `cat`.  In playing around, I used this variant to see what files I #include at least 10 times:

```
 cat *.c | sort | uniq -c | grep -e '^ *[0-9][0-9]\+ #include'
```

Comment: This won't find a header which is indirectly included (foo.c includes foo.h which includes bar.h, while baz.c includes baz.h which includes bar.h).

Comment: True, but neither would the suggested comm.  I took that as license to rely on strict equality and to ignore headers including other headers.  Without some help, mismatched whitespace or comments would foil `uniq -c` too.