# How can I remove common occurrences between 2 text files using the unix environment?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, text, grep, diff

Ok so I'm still learning the command line stuff like grep and diff and their uses within the scope of my project, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to approach this problem.

So I have 2 files, each containing hundreds of 20 character long strings.  lets call the files A and B.  I want to search through A and, using the values in B as keys, locate UNIQUE String entries that occur in A but not in B(there are duplicates so unique is the key here)

Any Ideas?

Also I'm not opposed to finding the answer myself, but I don't have a good enough understanding of the different command line scripts and their functions to really start thinking of how to use them together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unix command to find lines common in two files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files)

Comment: Verdammelt, thanks for the help! I like your answer because it shows me proper usage of grep and also introduces sort which is something I didn't know I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. With `comm` or with `grep`, `sort`, and `uniq`.

### `comm`

`comm afile bfile`

`comm` compares the files and outputs 3 columns, lines only in `afile`, lines only in `bfile`, and lines in common. The `-1`, `-3` switches tell `comm` to not print out those columns.

### `grep` `sort` `uniq`

`grep -F -v -file bfile afile | sort | uniq`

or just

`grep -F -v -file bfile afile | sort -u`

if your `sort` handles the `-u` option.

(note: the command `fgrep` if your system has it, is equivalent to `grep -F`.)

Comment: Or `grep -F` in lieu of `fgrep`.  The official POSIX standard for [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) no longer includes `egrep` (`grep -E`) or `fgrep` (`grep -F`) -- but real world implementations still include the original names, possibly as alternative names to the main `grep` binary.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) command (POSIX [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html)
) to do this.  See also [Unix command to find lines common in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files/).