# find lines from one file in another

Tags: unix, grep, string-matching, lines

So I have a file1.txt with a list of names, and a file2.txt with another list of names and I need a list with the names that are in both files.

I tried `grep-f file1.txt file2.txt > newlist.txt`  but for some reason it isn't working, and the newlist.txt has names that are not in file1.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what i could do to get only the names that are on both lists?

thank you.

Comment: What are the contents of the files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix command to find lines common in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files)

Answer (score 2):

If file1.txt and file2.txt are sorted, you could use 'comm'

```
comm -12 file1.txt file2.txt > newlist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `grep -f file1.txt file2.txt > newlist.txt` is a nice thought, but will give too much hits when file1.txt has "s10" and file2.txt has "slass100". You want to match the complete line, so try

```
grep -Fxf file1.txt file2.txt > newlist.txt
```

This should be faster than a solution that requires sorting first.

Answer (score 1):

If each the names in each list are unique, then you can find their intersection as follows:

```
sort file1.txt file2.txt | uniq -d > newlist.txt
```