# linux shell diff two files to get new line

Tags: shell, diff

I have two files and I want to get the new line by comparing two files, I know can use 'diff newfile oldfile' to get the new lines, but the output will include "<" and diff infomation which I don't want to have.

for example, now I have an oldfile:

```
a
b
c
```

and a newfile

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

the result of the 'diff newfile oldfile' will be

```
4,6d3
< d
< e
< f
```

but the result i want to have is

```
d
e
f
```

So how can i get this output? I have searchd many diff options but dont have any ideas

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way of finding lines in one file that are not in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: See also [BashFAQ/036](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036): "How can I get all lines that are: in both of two files (set intersection) or in only one of two files (set subtraction)."

Comment: you are able to obtain the needed result with "native" diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373810/113632), you can use [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) for this purpose.

```
comm -13 file1 file2
```

Will print only the lines of `file2` that don't exist in `file1`.

Comment: @SakuraKyouko Just remember that `comm` requires input files to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Native ***diff*** solution:

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' new.txt old.txt
```

The output:

```
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a==0)' oldfile newfile
d
e
f
```

or `grep` if the files are not that big (mind the partial matches):

```
$ grep -v -f oldfile newfile
d
e
f
```

or `join` (inputfiles need to be ordered):

```
$ join -v 2 oldfile newfile
d
e
f
```