# Is there a way to merge two tables and keep only the matching values using linux bash?

Tags: bash, shell, merge

I have two tables of string values, and the objetive is to make a new table that only keeps the matching values from both parent tables.

Example:

***TABLE1***

```
AX-18000257
AX-18000500
AX-18000816
AX-18000945
AX-18001189
AX-18001512
AX-18001524
```

***TABLE2***

```
AX-18000257
AX-18000512
AX-18000816
AX-18000947
AX-18001589
AX-18001525
AX-18001524
```

Expected output would be:

```
AX-18000257
AX-18000816
AX-18001189
AX-18001524
```

Comment: What are the rest of the columns in the table?

You can use `join` to join two files on specific fields.

Comment: `grep -v -f file2 file1 >> file3`

Comment: I can see you edited your question. Do you have two files of strings, where you need to keep all that are in both files?

Comment: @AndreasLouv I realize that I could make it easier just usinf cut -f2 from the original file so I work only with the columns I really need insted of the whole table. So now the question is simplified. I am looking for the join argument and its usage and see if it works with my example. It really helped!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell command to find lines common in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/shell-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with both:

```
grep -v -f file2 file1 >> file3 #thanks David Ranieri
```

Or with:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 file1 file 2 > file3
```

Using join with get you a warning *join: file 1 is not in sorted order
join: file 2 is not in sorted order* but the result is correct